# The ox of anti-art

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

I'm looking for a five digit number. The only thing you will need to know is

> The ox of anti-art

Comment: Should there be an [tag:anagram] tag?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what to tag this, but I can tell that it's not an anagram of any sort. It's a kind of a mix of a riddle and a cipher, and it requires some amount of prior knowledge (this is solvable without any prior knowledge, but I'd imagine it'd be pretty hard).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of prior knowledge might apply? For instance, does my prior knowledge of birds help me at all, or would I need to know something about squirrels, too?

Comment: Just being familiar with some concepts is enough. What could "anti-art" mean, and what is the "ox" of it?

Comment: What a mean way to refer to Nick Serota!

Comment: The ox of anti-art can be read as a hexadecimal number 0x0f+anti(art), where anti is some function/operation on the characters 'art'.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl "anti-art" could be more metaphorical, too. I'd keep going with this line of thought but you can't rot13 numbers

Comment: @question_asker bitwise not in ascii maybe? that would explain 'anti' :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be:

> 56026

My reasoning:

> [Dada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dada) is an art movement that has been referred to as anti-art.
>  0x is a common prefix used to denote a number as hexadecimal, notably in C, JavaScript, .etc
>  The hexadecimal value DADA is 56026 in decimal.

Comment: That's correct! (: